# Populating input fields using jQuery generated table

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsp

I'm trying to populate the fields in the input box of my modal. My modal appears after I click the `Edit` button in a table, and it should populate the fields according to the table row where the button is clicked. I generated the table solely with jQuery and fetched the data using JSON. This is the code generating my table:

```
$.getJSON("${pageContext.request.contextPath}/hostJSON", function (data) {
                var $table = $("#hostTable");
                $.each(data, function (i, h) {
                    if (h.status === "true") {
                        h.status = "<label class=\"label\" style=\"background-color: #b2c4aa;color:white\">Waiting</label>";
                    } else {
                        h.status = "<label class=\"label\" style=\"background-color: #FF8668;color:white\">Done</label>";
                    }
                    var $tr = $("<tr/>").attr('style', 'font-size:90%');
                    $("<td/>").html(h.id).appendTo($tr);
                    $("<td/>").html(h.name).appendTo($tr);
                    $("<td/>").html(h.contact).attr('style', 'text-align:center').appendTo($tr);
                    $("<td/>").html(h.email).attr('style', 'text-align:center').appendTo($tr);
                    $("<td/>").html(h.address).appendTo($tr);
                    $("<td/>").html(h.status).attr('style', 'text-align:center').appendTo($tr);
//BELOW IS THE REQUIRED LINE, WHICH IS A BUTTON:
                    $("<td/>").html("<span class=\"hostEditBtn\" data-host-name=\""+h.name+"\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#editEventHostModal\"><button class=\"btn btn-xs\" style=\"background-color:#b2c4aa;color:white\" data-toggle=\"tooltip\" title=\"Edit\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-pencil\"></span> Edit</button></span>").attr('style', 'text-align:center').appendTo($tr);
                    $tr.appendTo($table);
                });
            });
```

When the aforementioned button is clicked, it successfully opens up my modal but the field is not populated.

```
$(".hostEditBtn").on('click', function () {
    var $this=$(this);
    $("#hostName").val($this.attr('data-host-name'));
});
```

I'm only including the `Name` part so as to not make my post cluttered.

I feel I should also mention that I have a total of 3 `.jsp` files in this project, namely `index.jsp`, `modals.jsp`, and `jquery.jsp` which I include in my `index.jsp` file like so:

```
<%@include file="[name of file].jsp"%>
```

Why isn't it working? Is it because the custom attribute (`data-host-name`) is generated with jQuery? How can I make this work?

Comment: @VishalTajPM The modal is opened by this strip of code `data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#editEventHostModal\"` which is within the same `<span>` tag.

Comment: 1st thing you need to update is change `#hostEditBtn` ID to class `.hostEditBtn` as you are doing iteration so there is a chance of existing more than one span with the same id. as you inside `id` has to unique to entire `DOM`

Comment: @VishalTajPM Thanks a lot for pointing that out, I totally forgot about that, will update it on this post too. I made the respective changes but it still didn't populate the input box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code snippet. so for achieving this i haven't changed like i mentioned in the comment just update `#hostEditBtn` **ID** to **class** `.hostEditBtn` and inside the `.hostEditBtn` just refactored the code. please try this snippets:

inside the snippets instead of your ajax response i have defined a data object from which this data is populated do the action based on your logic.

```js
var $table = $("#hostTable");
var data = [{
 "status": true,
 "name": "test1",
 "contact": "12321312312",
 "email": 'test1@gmail.com',
 "address": 'test address 2'
},{
 "status": false,
 "name": "test2",
 "contact": "12321312312",
 "email": 'test2@gmail.com',
 "address": 'test address 2'
}]
$.each(data, function (i, h) {
   if (h.status === "true") {
      h.status = "<label class=\"label\" style=\"background-color: #b2c4aa;color:white\">Waiting</label>";
   } else {
     h.status = "<label class=\"label\" style=\"background-color: #FF8668;color:white\">Done</label>";
  }
  var $tr = $("<tr/>").attr('style', 'font-size:90%');
  $("<td/>").html(h.id).appendTo($tr);
  $("<td/>").html(h.name).appendTo($tr);
  $("<td/>").html(h.contact).attr('style', 'text-align:center').appendTo($tr);
  $("<td/>").html(h.email).attr('style', 'text-align:center').appendTo($tr);
  $("<td/>").html(h.address).appendTo($tr);
  $("<td/>").html(h.status).attr('style', 'text-align:center').appendTo($tr);
  $("<td/>").html("<span class=\"hostEditBtn\" data-host-name=\""+h.name+"\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#editEventHostModal\"><button class=\"btn btn-sm\" style=\"background-color:#b2c4aa;color:white\" data-toggle=\"tooltip\" title=\"Edit\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-pencil\"></span> Edit</button></span>").attr('style', 'text-align:center').appendTo($tr);
  $tr.appendTo($table);
});
                
                
                
$(".hostEditBtn").on('click', function () {
    $("#editEventHostModal #hostName").val($(this).attr('data-host-name'));
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<table id="hostTable">
</table>

<div id="editEventHostModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <input type="text" id="hostName" />
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow thanks a lot man. I just copied and pasted your code on my project and made a few tweaks based on my own data and it worked smooth as butter. No idea how, but it works. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $('body').on('click', '#hostEditBtn', function () {
      var attrValue = $(this).attr('data-host-name')
      $("#hostName").val(attrValue);
   });
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, I tried it but it didn't work.

Comment: Check no. of elements you getting on $('#hostEditBtn'). Is it returning a single element or an array?

Comment: How do I check the no. of elements I'm getting? Also, I had to make a few changes as pointed out by @VishalTajPM and I changed #hostEditBtn to .hostEditBtn.

Comment: Thanks, @CalvinNunes . I understood that I could have provided more information. Anyway, he got the solution. I'm happy.

Comment: I have provided my answer thinking you are maintaining Id 'hostEditBtn' UNIQUE across the page. So, Mine is to attach an event for dynamically added elements.  @VishalTajPM gave you detailed explanation what I mean.